# Sophie Germain-like primes and Cunningham-like chains

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A Sophie Germain prime is a prime number $p$ such that $2p+1$ is also prime. What do we know about other similar "Sophie Germain-like" primes, such that for instance $4p+1$ is prime (or generally, such that $2kp+1$ is prime for $k\in\mathbb{Z}, k>1$)?

Similarly, since a succession of primes such that $p$, $2p+1$, $2(2p+1)+1$, $\ldots$ is called a Cunningham chain, are there other "Cunningham-like" chains such that $p$, $4p+1$, $4(4p+1)+1$, $\ldots$, or even $p$, $2p+1$, $4(2p+1)+1$, $8(4(2p+1)+1)+1$, $\ldots$ are primes?

Comment: This is open, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128212/special-primes-with-p-4p1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: It is also not a duplicate of the post you linked as duplicate...

Answer (score 8):

From $\gcd(2p,1)=1$, according to [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) there will be infinitely many primes of such form, i.e. $2pn+1$.

Comment: Imported from a question formerly marked as duplicate. I am not sure if it matches the intent of this question exactly, but it seems that the questioner had approved the duplicated, so they think so. The point is that here  $p$ is fixed and  $n$ is free, while in Sophie Germain like problems the $n$ is fixed and the $p$ can vary.